# Install m2e in eclipse without install maven in system

Tags: maven

I recently try to use maven in my eclipse project. In maven official website there are several step that I must to accomplish to configure maven  side by side with eclipse. But I know there is a m2eclipse plugins if I need to use maven. But I don't know if I can use this plugins with maven installed in system or not.

So can I use this plugins without maven been installed in system or not ?

Answer (score 2):

The m2e plugin brings a copy of Maven 3.0.4 and installs it inside of Eclipse so the plugin can use it. This is enough to build Maven projects inside of Eclipse. No external installation is needed.

You must start Eclipse with a JDK, though. A JRE isn't enough. If you're unsure: Look for the file `lib/tools.jar`. When it's there: You're good.

This copy isn't accessible from the command line. If you want to build from the command line as well or if you need a newer version of Maven than 3.0, you need to install Maven and configure the plugin accordingly.